# Problema de un JComboBox en un JTable

Tags: java, eclipse

Tengo una tabla `tbDocSolicitud`, que está llena de información de la base de datos Sql Server y presenta 18 columnas.

En la columna número 13 `Centro Costo Destino` he añadido un `JComboBox` ,llamado `cboCentroCostoDestino`, para que aparezca cada vez que se agrega una fila, este Combo es llenado mediante base de datos con un procedimiento almacenado.

**Funcionamiento el programa**

Primero por cada fila escojo el centro de costo destino osea escojo donde se irá la fila que seleccione, una vez que ya estén las filas seleccionadas con su centro de costo destino respectivo presiono el botón enviar.

El problema es que cuando se envía las filas seleccionadas se envía con el centro de costo destino escogido al ultimo osea se envía el último centro de costo destino que le asigne a la última fila seleccionada y no se envía los centro de costo destinos respectivos por cada fila seleccionada.

Este es el código que agrego el `JComboBox` al `JTable`:

```
TableColumn col = tbDocSolicitud.getColumnModel().getColumn(13);
col.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(cboCentroCostoDestino));
```

Este es el código del boton enviar:

```
protected void btnEnviarActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int[] selectedRow = tbDocSolicitud.getSelectedRows();
        int i = tbDocSolicitud.getSelectedRow();
        if(i == -1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Seleccione los documentos que desea solicitar");
        }
        else{
            for(int t : selectedRow){
                String codArchivo = (String) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 0);
                String codCentroCosto = (String) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 1);
                String tipoArchivo = (String) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 4);
                String doc = (String) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 6).toString().trim();
                String nivelArchivo = (String) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 7);
                String lote = (String) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 9);
                String fila = (String) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 10);
                String usuarioSolicita = Constante.idUsuario;
                Objeto object = (Objeto) cboCentroCostoDestino.getSelectedItem();
                String cod_centroCostoDestino = ((Objeto)object).getCodigo();
                String centroCostoOrigen = Constante.c_ccosto;

                if (cod_centroCostoDestino.equals("0")){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Seleccione el Destino del Documento","Alerta",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    cboCentroCostoDestino.requestFocus();
                }
                else{
                    MovimientoArchivoDTO m = new MovimientoArchivoDTO();
                    m.setC_c_archivo(codArchivo);
                    CentroCostoDTO c = new CentroCostoDTO();
                    c.setC_ccosto(codCentroCosto);
                    m.setC_ccosto(c);
                    m.setC_ccosto_origen(centroCostoOrigen);
                    m.setC_ccosto_destino(cod_centroCostoDestino);
                    m.setC_tipo_doc(tipoArchivo);
                    m.setC_t_doc(doc);
                    m.setC_c_nivel_archivo(nivelArchivo);
                    m.setLote(lote);
                    m.setFila(fila);
                    m.setC_c_usuario_solicita(usuarioSolicita);
                    int estado = x.RegistrarSolicitud_SA(m);
                    if (estado == 1){
                        documentos = doc.split(" ");
                        for (String value : documentos) {
                            notificacion = notificacion + "-" + value + " " + "para" + " " + cod_centroCostoDestino + " \n";
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        mensaje("Error en enviar");
                    }
                }
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new Object[] {notificacion}, "Solicitud Enviada", 1, null);
            ListarDocumentoSA(estado_flg);
        }
    }
```

Se envía todo bien pero como digo el problema es que por cada fila no se envía con su respectivo centro de costo destino que escojo, se envía con el ultimo centro de costo destino que le asigno a la última fila.

En esta imagen voy seleccionando y asignando su destino del documento (centro de costo destino que viene ser un `JComboBox`) a cada fila que desea enviar a solicitud:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código con el que lleno de informacion al `JComboBox` `cboCentroCostoDestino`:

```
void CargarCentroCostoDestino() throws Exception{
        Connection cn = null;
        PreparedStatement pstm = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            combo = new DefaultComboBoxModel<Objeto>();
            cn = new SqlConexion().getConectar();
            String sql = "Select c_ccosto, x_ccosto from fccosto";
            pstm = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = pstm.executeQuery();
            combo.addElement(new Objeto("0", "Seleccione"));
            while(rs.next()){
                combo.addElement(new Objeto(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2)));
            }
            cboCentroCostoDestino.removeAllItems();
            cboCentroCostoDestino.setModel(combo);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try {
                if (rs != null)
                    rs.close();
                if (pstm != null)
                    pstm.close();
                if (cn != null)
                    cn.close();
            } 
            catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: si es informacion sensible puede borrarla con un editor de imagenos o simplemente no subir esa imagen. Mientras tenega tiempo usare la respuesta como si fuera un chat ya que usted no puede aun, pondre update para cualquier cosa.Saludos

Comment: Añadi mas informacion en mi pregunta

Comment: el problema es que cuando ya termine de asignar el centro de costo destino a las filas seleccionadas solo se graba el ultimo que asigné y las demás filas seleccionadas se graba con ese ultimo centro de costo asignado

Comment: probe con el update 1 y me sale el siguiente error: `Adicional.Objeto cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

Comment: umm pues pensaba que el combo funcionaba para rellenar las filas, pruebe esto aunque no se si funcionara `Objeto object = (Objeto) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 13);` y `String cod_centroCostoDestino =  object.toString();` y me comenta. siento que no le funcionar lo anterio estaba casi convencido que si le funcionaria.Saludos

Comment: Ya me llegó a salir, utilicé `Objeto object = (Objeto) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 13);` y `String cod_centroCostoDestino = object.toString();`

Comment: Gracias nuevamente por tu ayuda

Comment: Voy a modificar la respuesta para dejar la solucion, me alegra que lo resolviera, pero no tanto el tiempo que tarde en dar con ella o tradamos mejor dicho. Saludos

Comment: me acabo de fijar bien es su error aunque ya tiene la solucion quizas esto tambien le funcione -> `Objeto object = (Objeto) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 13);` y `String cod_centroCostoDestino = object.getCodigo();` si no pues simpre puede seguir con la solucion que encontramos, pero ahora entiendo por que no sabia que era `.getCodigo();` pues era `Objeto object...` y al leerlo rapido asumia esto `Object object` la clase object de java ja. y claro lo mismo para la parte de defaulcomboboxmodel. si puede me gustaria saber si le funciona igual con lo mencionado arriba gracias. Saludos

Comment: Claro tambien probé con eso y si me salió, gracias.

Comment: @AngelAngel me gustaría que si me pudieras ayudar con mi siguiente pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/64220/no-aparece-el-jprogressbar-cuando-lo-ejecuto-java

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57426/discussion-between-angelica-and-angel-angel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UPDATE 1:

pues pensaba que el combo solo funcionaba haciendo de funcion para rellenar las filas y le funcionaria, pruebe lo siguiente:

```
Objeto object = (Objeto) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 13);
String cod_centroCostoDestino = object.toString();
```

o

```
Objeto object = (Objeto) tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 13); y 
String cod_centroCostoDestino = object.getCodigo();
```

y me comente. Siento que no le funcionar lo anterior estaba casi convencido que si le funcionaria.

> UPDATE:

Hace mucho tiempo que no trabajo con este tipo de aplicaciones, pero intente este cambio:

```
    //String cod_centroCostoDestino = ((Objeto)object).getCodigo(); <-- pero no se que recupera getCodigo(); aun asi intente el cambio 
    //Objeto object = (Objeto) cboCentroCostoDestino.getSelectedItem();
    String cod_centroCostoDestino = tbDocSolicitud.getValueAt(t, 13);
```

tambien puede mirar esto:

```
    String cod_centroCostoDestino = tbDocSolicitud.getModel().getValueAt(t, 13);
```

Recordando un poco al fijarme mejor creo que el JComboBox se utiliza para editar la celda y este no contiene los datos para la celda, en cuestion, posible que por eso al obtener el valor obtenga la ultima que se seleciono en el combo_box, aun tengo la duda de que retorna en una de sus lineas `.getCodigo();`

Comment: @Angelica puede comentarme si esto soluciona su problema y si no, si esto genera un comportamiento diferente ect.

Comment: el problema es cuando se guarda en la base de datos, osea para que se pueda enviar los documentos tengo que asignarles un centro de costo destino a cada uno mediante un jcombobox, cuando ya terminé de asignarles y le doy al boton enviar las filas que he seleccionado no se les llega a asignar su respectivo centro de costo destino si no se les asigna el ultimo centro de costo destino que le asigné a la ultima fila.

Comment: Usted probo el codigo que le deje al final, la verdad es que ahora no tengo mucho tiempo, pero pienso que su error es cosa de fijarse en lo que hace el codigo al leerlo no intente leerlo pensando en lo que quiere que haga, usted tiene el codigo entero y sabe como esta funcionando su programa yo muchas cosas tengo que imaginarmlas, o cosas que usted puede no estar comentado y son obvias para usted pero no para mi, con esto no le quiero decir que su pregunta este mal, si que nesitaria tiempo para que usted me fuera clarando las dudas que pueda tener al probar los codigos o cambios que le digo.

Comment: @Angelica podria poner una captura con el del comportamiento que esta teniendo con el codigo suyo, y aclarando como quiere que se comporte en pocas palabra en referencia a la imagen, por otro lado podria poner una captura de como se comporta con los cambios que le comente.Saludos

Comment: ya coloque captura

Comment: el código que me pasaste ya lo añadí y el resultado sale en el mensaje que me indica los documentos que he enviado y a donde lo he enviado pero eso no es el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba cogiendo el valor del combo en la fila seleccionada. tal que así:

```
Objeto object = (Objeto) cboCentroCostoDestino.getItemAt(t);
String cod_centroCostoDestino = ((Objeto)object).getCodigo();
```